# I remote git to GitHub, It wrong

Tags: git, github

I have a local repository.  I want to put the repository for my GitHub.  There is something wrong when I do it.

How do I put the repository to my GitHub?  I do this :

```
git init 
git add ........
git commit ..
```

Then I do this:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:jiexishede/StudyMethod.git
git push origin master
```

Then, the error is showing:

```
To git@github.com:jiexishede/StudyMethod.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:jiexishede/StudyMethod.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
jiexishede:StudyMethod lilonglong$ git remote set-url origin git@github.com:jiexishede/StudyMethod.git
```

How to fix it?

Comment: I have a "README.md" in the GitHub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that there is some file in the github server, but not in your local repository. Just use `git pull` command to get them or use `git push -f` to push your new commit force.

If you have the same file in local and the server, but one of them is newer than another. You have to solve the conflict before `git push` or `git push`(if git can not auto solve the conflict).

So if you have another new file in the server but not in local, or you have another file in the server is newer than the local's but you haven't edited the local's. just use these commands:

```
git pull
git push
```

But however, if your files has some conflict, you have to pull and edit them. Like:

`git pull`

when you finished solve the conflict, then you can push it to the server.

However, if you don't need the file that on the server. You just need push it use

```
git push --force
```

or

```
git push -f
```

this command will auto solve the conflict because it's more like:

> delete file on the server first
>
> then push your local file to the server

Comment: Can you give me a detail answer. If you can give me a few line of command , so I can know how to write.

Comment: Your answer is not the excellent one. I manually resolve conflicts. Then I use git to add the file,commit, push. It work .

Comment: Please edit your answer again. Someone else can use your answer fix the error.

Comment: Yes I will but please wait, I'm writing.

Comment: finished, what do you think of this?

Answer (score 2):

There are commits in the upstream repository you have not integrated into your local branch.

```
git fetch
git merge origin/master
git push
```

Comment: Something against rebasing :-) ?

Comment: jiexishede:StudyMethod lilonglong$ git push origin master
To git@github.com:jiexishede/StudyMethod.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:jiexishede/StudyMethod.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
jiexishede:StudyMethod lilonglong$

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen When advising a new user? Thing about what can go wrong with rebasing compared to non-history destructive merges.

Comment: @jiexishede If you remembered the fetch, and the merge succeeded, your branch will not stay behind master. Run the commands again.

Comment: I do again. It shows the error below.                           jiexishede:remote-test lilonglong$ git push origin master
To git@github.com:jiexishede/remote-test.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:jiexishede/remote-test.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
jiexishede:remote-test lilonglong$